# JavaScript set object key by variable

Tags: javascript

I am building some objects in JavaScript and pushing those objects into an array, I am storing the key I want to use in a variable then creating my objects like so:

```
var key = "happyCount";
myArray.push( { key : someValueArray } );
```

but when I try to examine my array of objects for every object the key is `"key"` instead of the value of the variable key. Is there any way to set the value of the key from a variable?

Fiddle for better explanation:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fr6eY/3/

Comment: The solution in ES6 is to put the variable in square brackets in order to evaluate it.
`var key = "happyCount";
myArray.push({ [key]: someValueArray });`

Comment: @DanCron Sounds great, but when will 99%+ of 'browsers' in the user base be ES6-capable?

Comment: @Jake The only browser that currently does not support this es6 feature is IE11: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_computed_properties

Comment: @Jake That's a good point. One possible solution is to use babel to transpile ES6 into ES5.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen You can't normally assume everyone is using the latest version of whatever browser - a significant number of web users have a significantly out of date browser.  Your use of ES6-specific constructs will break your site for them.

Comment: @Jake That is exactly what babel is for. As Dan Cron mentions above.

Comment: @Jake  Like Hunter says, it's best not to code for ES5 users.  If you need to support older browsers, pollyfill & transpile.  It's now 2018,  not 2009, we really need to move on.

Comment: In my case, Dan Cron's tip was fastest to correct my code. As to what Keith says, I definitely agree. As to what @Hunter McMillen said about IE11, I am wondering more generally: Is it  reasonable to take into account Microsoft browsers now, since their world market share amounts to peanuts nowadays? Just as Firefox (my favourite one), they are bound to die presently, including Opera. Quoting Keith: ' let's move on'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](/q/2274242/90527)

Answer (score 3011, accepted):

You need to make the object first, then use `[]` to set it.

```
var key = "happyCount";
var obj = {};

obj[key] = someValueArray;
myArray.push(obj);
```

---

UPDATE 2021:

[Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) feature was introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) that allows you to dynamically compute the names of the object properties in JavaScript object literal notation.

```
const yourKeyVariable = "happyCount";
const someValueArray= [...];

const obj = {
    [yourKeyVariable]: someValueArray,
}
```

Comment: Where did you define `myArray` ?

Comment: @AlexG: It was used in the question.

Comment: Note, that things changed [for the better in ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2274327/444255), i.e. `{[key]:someValueArray}`

Comment: @Frank Nocke I'm looking forward to be able to use it in about 10 years time when all the 'browsers' we have to support support it...

Comment: @Jake you can program in ES6 or ES7 today, and have Babel compile your JS file back to ES5. This is how webapps are built nowadays.

Comment: for those who wonder how this ES6 feature is called: it is `Computed property name`

Comment: Specifically, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring

Comment: Couldn't you do  ```{`${key}`:value}```

Comment: @AidanWelch: I tried that and got `SyntaxError: expected property name, got '${'`.

Comment: `{`${key}`:value}` also requires ES6 for template literals

Answer (score 612):

**In ES6, you can do like this.**

```
var key = "name";
var person = {[key]:"John"}; // same as var person = {"name" : "John"}
console.log(person); // should print  Object { name="John"}
```

```js
    var key = "name";
    var person = {[key]:"John"};
    console.log(person); // should print  Object { name="John"}
```

Its called [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), its implemented using bracket notation( square brackets) `[]`

Example: `{ [variableName] : someValue }`

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also
> supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression
> in brackets [], that will be computed and used as the property name.

**For ES5, try something like this**

```
var yourObject = {};

yourObject[yourKey] = "yourValue";

console.log(yourObject );
```

**example:**

```
var person = {};
var key = "name";

person[key] /* this is same as person.name */ = "John";

console.log(person); // should print  Object { name="John"}
```

```js
    var person = {};
    var key = "name";
    
    person[key] /* this is same as person.name */ = "John";
    
    console.log(person); // should print  Object { name="John"}
```

Comment: I provided a solution that I think may be of some interest to people at this link using underscore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640988/how-do-i-interpolate-a-variable-as-a-key-in-a-javascript-object/30608422#30608422

Answer (score 25):

## The Reality

The problem in JS is simply that:

```
{ x: 2 }
```

is THE SAME as:

```
{ "x": 2 }
```

(even if you have `x` a variable defined!)

## Solution

Add square brackets <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> around the **identifier** of the key:

```js
var key = "happyCount";
myArray.push( { [key] : someValueArray } );
```

(Nowadays the keyword `var` is not much used, so please use instead `const` or `let`)

### tldr;

[image]

Answer (score 16):

In ES6 We can write objects like this

```
const key= "Name";
const values = "RJK"

const obj = {
    [key]: values,
}
```

Comment: This is not a different answer than existing ones.

Comment: Nice. No use of push.

Answer (score 14):

```
var key = "happyCount";
myArray.push( { [key] : someValueArray } );
```

Comment: This is not a different answer than existing ones.

Answer (score 11):

Use this.

```
var key = 'a'
var val = 'b'

console.log({[key]:val})

//a:'b'
```

Comment: This answer was already given by @kiranvj

Comment: I do like how I can get the answer very quickly, as opposed to @kiranvjs answer

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, it should look something like this

```
    let title ="Current User";
    type User = {
      [key:string | number | symbol]: any
    };

    let myVar: User = {};

    myVar[ title ] = "App Developer";

    console.log(myVar)// Prints: { Current User:"App Developer"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let key = "name";
let name= "john";
const obj ={
 id:01
}
obj[key] = name;
console.log(obj); // output will {id:01,name:"john}
```

Use square brackets shown it will set as key

Comment: This is not a different answer than existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
var key = "happyCount";
const someValueArray= [1, 3, 5, 7];
```

To use `key` as is:

```
myArray.push({
  [key]: someValueArray
});
```

To use `key` with some other prefix or suffix:

```
myArray.push({
  [`${key}Array`]: someValueArray
});
```

Source: [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)