# Push into array of arrays in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

My schema of **users** is like this:

```
{
name: String,
posts:[
    {
    title: String,
    comments:[
      {
        country: String,
        tags:[
         {
            title: String
         }]
      }]
    }]
}
```

I want to push a tag into a **specific comment** of **specific post**.

I tried with this:

```
db.getCollection('users').update(
{"name" : "javier", "posts.title": "sometitle", "posts.comments.country": "ES"},
{$push:{"posts.$.comments.$.tags":{"title":"sometag"}}});
```

But mongoDB doesnt accept using two $. So how can I push the tag?, is it possible in mongoDB? Do I have bad concept of schemas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's really nested. you might consider putting comments in it's own collection.

Comment: I think this can be helpful: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603542/mongodb-update-data-in-nested-field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603542/mongodb-update-data-in-nested-field)