# How to update a nested model in mongoose and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, model, mean-stack

I'm building a MEAN stack web application.

I have a model in `mongoose` like this. A model name `analyses`, where inside , there is a property call `points` which is another small model name `analysis`

```
//model file
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

var analysis = new Schema({ 
  ref_id: String,
  ele_name: String,
  pos_x: Number,
  pos_y: Number,
  pos_pix_x: Number,
  pos_pix_y: Number,
});

var analyses = new Schema({    
  img_id: String,
  store_file_name:String,
  points: {
    type: [analysis],
    default: undefined
  },    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('analyses', analyses);
```

In the database , after I create an entry. there something like this 
[image]

As you can see, there an id of `analyses (5bb...820e)` inside have an array of points ( `analysis`), each has their own id `( 5bb...26d)`

Now if I want to update this. I use `ExpressJS` to define the update API of the server

```
// API define file
var express = require('express');
var analysesRoutes = express.Router();

// Require Item model in our routes module
var Analyses = require('../models/analyses');

//  Defined update route
analysesRoutes.route('/update/:id').put(function (req, res) {
  Analyses.findById(req.params.id, function(err, analyses) {
    if (!analyses)
      return next(new Error('Could not load Document'));
    else {
      for ( item of Object.keys(req.body)){
        analyses[item] = req.body[item];
      }
      analyses.save().then(analyses => {
        res.json({...analyses, status: 200});
      })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send("unable to update the database");
        });
    }
  });
});
```

**But my problem here** is if I want to update only 1 `analysis` point, I have to send the request to update the big `analyses` object ( call out id `5bb...820e`). Something like this :

```
//service file
  updateAnalyses(newObj, id) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/analyses/update/' + id;

    this
      .http
      .put(uri, newObj)
      .subscribe(res => console.log('Done'));
  }
 // Where newObj here is a big analyses object contains all the unnecessary detail + the point need to be updated
```

In fact, that point also have an id ( `5bb..26d`) itself, **is there anyway to update directly to that analysis point ??**

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was answered before in Stack overflow.
You can refer to it from here: [MongoDB update data in nested field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603542/mongodb-update-data-in-nested-field/19607157)

P.S. There are many answers related to  mongodb. Personally the `parent.$.child` notation worked for me.