# Mongoose (mongodb) + Node.JS - Upsert nested Array (create or update)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with upsert into nested array.
My schema is:

```
new Schema({
  itemId: { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true },
  nestedItems: [{
    nestedItemId: { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true },
    nestedArray: [
      {
        id1: { type: String, required: true },
        id2: { type: String, required: true },
        booleanItem: { type: Boolean, required: true },
      },
    ],
  }],
})
```

I need to upsert nestedArray.
For example:

`{id1: "1", id2: "2", booleanItem: true}`

will save

`nestedArray: [{id1: "1", id2: "2", booleanItem: true}]`

and then

`{id1: "1", id2: "2", booleanItem: false}`

update it to

`nestedArray: [{id1: "1", id2: "2", booleanItem: false}]`

etc..

Is it possible to do it in one db request?

I tried something, but it has not create new item

```
await Model.updateOne(
  {
    itemId,
  },
  {
    $set: { 'nestedItems.$[nestedItem].nestedArray.$[nestedArrayItem].booleanItem': true },
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [{
      'nestedItem.nestedItemId': 'nestedItemId',
    }, {
      'nestedArrayItem.id1': 'id1',
      'nestedArrayItem.id2': 'id2',
    }],
    upsert: true,
  }
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603542/mongodb-update-data-in-nested-field
Check this

Comment: it is not double nested

Comment: you need to go with [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), it is not possible to upsert single array or nested array using single command