# jQuery array set both key and value and send array via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I want to send key value pairs to my php page, but I need to set the key and value dynamically from data tags.

Here's the code I have until now:

```
function send(){
    var attr = new Array();

    var key = $('#add').attr('data-key');
    var value = $('#add').attr('data-value');

    attr.push({ key : value });

    var data = {attributes: attr};

    $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result)
            }
    });

}
```

This is not the actual code, it's just the basic functionality.

The problem is here:

```
attr.push({ key : value });
```

The 'key' is not taken as the variable I've set.

Can I please get some help? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you very much!

Comment: This might help: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Comment: why don't you just serialize form or div inputs ? `var data = $('#myformid').serialize();` then let php take the care of submited keys and values

Comment: Maybe it's not a form...

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a form. Still, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update:

Since ECMAScript 6 (2015) it's possible to use [computed object property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), which is supported by all current browsers and other JavaScript environments:

`attr.push({ [key] : value });`

---

## Original Answer:

Use the [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets):

Instead of `attr.push({ key : value });` use

```
var object = {}; 
object[key] = value;
attr.push(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did this:

```
var key = "abc", value="pqr";
arr.push({key: value});
```

It would have following:

`[Object { key="pqr"}]`

which is **not** what you wanted..

You have to be able to do this:

```
var arr = new Array();
keyValuePair = {};
keyValuePair[key]=value; // set your dynamic values

arr.push(keyValuePair);
```

Now you have:

```
[Object { abc="pqr"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to set dynamic key and values of an array.

```
 var key = 1;  //your dynamic values
 var value = 2;
 var key1 = 3;
 var value1 = 5;

var myArray = new Array();
myArray[key] = value;  // set array key and values
myArray[key1] = value1;

// show the values stored
for (var i in myArray) {
    alert('key is: ' + i + ', value is: ' + myArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manage "data" as a string.

```
   data = "";
data += key + ":"+value;
```

of course a form serialize could be better if you have input in a form.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

JavaScript

```
var objects = [];

var newObject= new Object();
newObject.key = value;

objects.push(newObject);
```

Then, you can POST this objects-array using AJAX. In your PHP, you could retrieve the value again:

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['objects'] as $object) {
    echo $object['value'];
}
```

Not sure if it's what you need, but it does work, if I'm correct.