# Javascript associative array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, but I want the belongsto var to be retrieved as the key using the var value and not the var name:

```
var belongsto = panel.attr('data-belongsto');
var panelid = panel.attr('id');

tabValue.push({belongsto:panelid}); console.log(tabValue);
```

this returns [{'belongsto':'12345'}]

As you can see the the script takes belongsto as the key name but I need it to take the content of the variable.

Any help is appreciated, thanks-

Comment: Look for "bracket notation".

Comment: `var d = {}; d[belongsto] = panelid; tabValue.push(d);`

Comment: There are no associative arrays ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable

Comment: Also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242/218196. However, in ES6 it will be possible to use any expression as property name. It will look something like `{[belongsto]: panelid}`. (See https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer for more "info")

Comment: @FelixKling Interesting.. I have been searching for an alternate way as you specified..

Answer (score 0):

Create the object first

```
var obj = {};
obj[belongsto] = panelid;
tabValue.push(obj);
```