# How do I use a variable for a property name in an object initializer/literal?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function SaveToStore(thisObjName) {
  var thisObj = $('#'+thisObjName);
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    "cbSO" : thisObj.is(':checked')
  });
}
```

I would like to use the argument `thisObjName`, which contains `"cbSO"`, as the key (property name) in the object I'm passing into `chrome.storage.sync.set`:

```
function SaveToStore(thisObjName) {
  var thisObj = $('#'+thisObjName);
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    thisObjName : thisObj.is(':checked')
  });
}
```

But that's creating a property with the name `thisObjName`, not `cbSO`. How do I use the value of the argument as the key?

Comment: We _really_ need a canonical question for this.

Comment: @Xan: This question was written fairly generically, so I've genericized it further; it can be the canonical. Sure, it's not the first time this has been asked, but that's true for lots of now-canonical questions, and this one was fairly clean to start with, so... :-)

Comment: @Xan: I think there already is one, at least I always use it as a duplicate target. The other two questions with good answers are linked in the comments [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: If you want to make a really clean canonical question, please strip it of all the jquery and chrome stuff and focus on the object literal. I'd suggest however that we use either [this highest-voted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11508463/1048572) or [this most-frequently-linked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242/1048572) one to start with (and ask a mod to make them community-wiki).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two answers to this question:

- The answer for ECMAScript5 (ES5) and below
- The answer for ECMAScript6 (ES6) and up

#### The answer for ECMAScript5 (ES5) and below

You can't do it with a property initializer, the part before the `:` is always used *literally*, it's not an expression that gets evaluated.

To create a property with a name from a variable, you have to create the object separately, then set the property using brackets notation (and then pass the object to the function):

```
function SaveToStore(thisObjName) {
  var thisObj = $('#'+thisObjName), args = {};
  args[thisObjName] = thisObj.is(':checked');
  chrome.storage.sync.set(args);
}
```

#### The answer for ECMAScript6 (ES6) and up

You can do that with a *computed property name* in the [property initializer](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer). It looks like this:

```
function SaveToStore(thisObjName) {
  var thisObj = $('#'+thisObjName);
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
      [thisObjName]: thisObj.is(':checked') // ES6 syntax! Not currently widespread
  });
}
```

Note the `[]` around the `thisObjName` on the left-hand side of the `:` — those indicate that what's inside is an *expression*, not a literal.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
Now its working like expected