# Add a dynamic class name

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In [react.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) I need to add a dynamic class name to a `div`.
Using [react-addons](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/addons.html), I tried it the following way but in vain:

```
var addons = require('react-addons');
var cx = addons.classSet;   

var Overlay = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        var prod_id = this.props.prop_id;
        var large_prod_class = 'large_prod_modal_' + prod_id;

        var modal_classes = cx({
            'large_prod_modal': true,
            large_prod_class: true,
            'hidden': true
        });

        return (<div className={modal_classes}>lorem ipsum</div>);
    }
});
```

And `Overlay` component is used in the following way:

```
<Overlay prod_id="9" />
```

The prop (i.e: `prod_id`) value is random however. I do not get the `large_prod_modal_9` class for the `div`. All the classes I get are `large_prod_modal`,`large_prod_class` and `hidden`

How to get the `large_prod_modal_9` class for the `div`?

Comment: This is technically a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable

Answer (score 9):

The classSet addon is deprecated as of 0.13.  The offical recomendation is to use [JedWatson/classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames).

```
var cx = require('classnames');   
var Overlay = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        var prod_id = this.props.prop_id;
        var modal_classes  = cx('large_prod_modal_' + prod_id, {
            'large_prod_modal': true,
            'hidden': true
        });

        return (<div className={modal_classes}>lorem ipsum</div>);

    }
});
```

If all of the class names are always true, you can just pass them as strings.

```
var prod_id = this.props.prop_id;
var modal_classes  = cx(
    'large_prod_modal_' + prod_id,
    'large_prod_modal'
    'hidden'
});
```

You can mix strings and objects as desired.  You don't get this flexibility with the addon classSet.

Answer (score 3):

example solution for this would be:

```
 dynamicClass: function(){
     return "large_prod_modal large_prod_modal_" + this.props.prod_id + " hidden"
 }
 render: function(){
   return (<div className={this.dynamicClass()}>lorem ipsum</div>) 
 }
```

You can't generate dynamicly the key in JSON object so thats why you get 'large_prod_class' and it's correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var classes = {
    'large_prod_modal': true,
    'hidden': true
 };
 classes[large_prod_class] = true;
 var modal_classes = cx(classes);
```

You can see [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) about adding dynamic properties to objects at run time (dynamically):

> This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime).

Comment: where is it documented ?

Comment: the classSet function takes a normal javascript object so, I don't think it needs documentation...

Comment: added documentation to my answer.