# how to make a working variable for object key in jquery to avoid extra codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I'm using TweenMax script to add styles to a div on scrolling. I want to have different styles on different page resolutions. So, I added an `if` condition as a solution. How can I use a variable to avoid adding extra codes inside the `if` condition?! I added `$direction` and only `direction` as a variable, but, it seems that it doesn't work.

```
if (($(window).width() <= 900) && ($(window).width() >= 409)) {  
    var $direction = 'left';
} else {
    var $direction = 'top';
}
$(".softwares").children(".row").each(function(a) {
     $(this).delay(150 * a).fadeIn(0, function() {
         TweenMax.to($(this), .3, {
            $direction: 45 * a,
            opacity: 1,
            ease: Back.easeOut
         })
     })
});
```

**I looked upon lot's of questions in stackoverflow, and I used `[]` to come to a solution, but I could not make it work.**

I don't want the code to be like: (the extra code which I want to avoid)

```
$(".softwares").children(".row").each(function(a) {
     if (($(window).width() <= 900) && ($(window).width() >= 409)) {  
         // opacity: 1, ease: Back.easeOut are extra codes in both conditions
         var options = {left: 45 * a, opacity: 1, ease: Back.easeOut};
     } else {
         var options = {top: 45 * a, opacity: 1, ease: Back.easeOut};
     }
     $(this).delay(150 * a).fadeIn(0, function() {
         TweenMax.to($(this), .3, options) // use options object here
     })
});
```

Comment: what are the extra codes ?

Comment: the extra code which I want to avoid is added

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$(".softwares").children(".row").each(function(a) {
     if (($(window).width() <= 900) && ($(window).width() >= 409)) {  
         // set options object directly in your condition
         var options = {left: 45 * a, opacity: 1, ease: Back.easeOut};
     } else {
         var options = {top: 45 * a, opacity: 1, ease: Back.easeOut};
     }
     $(this).delay(150 * a).fadeIn(0, function() {
         TweenMax.to($(this), .3, options) // use options object here
     })
});
```

But this makes you write a few extra codes.

Otherwise, you could check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable) for more information on how having dynamic keys.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good solution. So, +1 . But, let's see if there's another solution better than this

Comment: Yep, have you had a look to the link provided? :)

Comment: I somehow corrected your answer to avoid "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined"