# How to convert boolean object to array

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

How can I take a simple object with boolean values and convert it to an array where only those keys whose values are true end up in the array?

E.g.:

```
myObject = {
  option1: true,
  option2: false,
  option3: true,
  option4: true
}
```

becomes

```
['option1','option3','option4']
```

I tried using `_.pick(myObject, Boolean)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573598/javascript-underscore-turn-array-of-booleans-into-array-of-strings), but that simply produced an empty object. I'm using Typescript, so if there's any Typescript magic I can use to accomplish this, I'm up for that, too.

Comment: `Object.entries(myObject).filter(([_,v]) => v).map(([k]) => k)`

Comment: Gorgeous. This comment should be an (and the) answer!

Answer (score 12):

This is easily achievable with vanilla js.

```js
let myObject = {
  option1: true,
  option2: false,
  option3: true,
  option4: true
}

let array = Object.keys(myObject).filter(key => myObject[key]);

console.log(array);
```

You can see a working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20myObject%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20option1%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20option2%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20option3%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20option4%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20array%20%3D%20Object.keys(myObject).filter(key%20%3D%3E%20myObject%5Bkey%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(array)%3B).

Comment: Good solution with pure javascript :) .. but why you mentioned `vanilla js`?

Comment: ooh.. just a alias.. anyway, +1 ^^

Answer (score 7):

A lodash solution is to use [`lodash#pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pickBy) and [`lodash#keys`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keys) to get all truthy keys.

```
var result = _(myObject).pickBy().keys().value();
```

```js
var myObject = {
  option1: true,
  option2: false,
  option3: true,
  option4: true
};

var result = _(myObject).pickBy().keys().value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in `map` function of `Lodash` it also handle Object, instead of a collection. using `lodash` the simplest solution will be using `_.reduce`.

Ohk.. let's see how `_.map` works with object:

```
var array = _(myObject).map((v, k)=> v && k).compact().value();
```

```js
var myObject = {
  option1: true,
  option2: false,
  option3: true,
  option4: true
}
var array = _(myObject).map((v, k)=> v && k).compact().value();

console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

With the same concept, (that `lodash` and `underscore` handle object if you pass in place of array) you can use `_.reduce` function and do the trick in one go:

```
var array = _.reduce(myObject, (i, v, k) => v && !i.push(k) || i, []);
```

```js
var myObject = {
  option1: true,
  option2: false,
  option3: true,
  option4: true
}
var array = _.reduce(myObject, (i, v, k) => v && !i.push(k) || i, []);

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```