# Is there a one-liner for creating an object literal in Javascript with a key named after a parameter?

Tags: javascript

i.e.:

```
assert(createObj('foo', 5)) == {foo: 5}
```

One implementation would of course be:

```
function createObj(key, val) {
  var ret = {};
  ret[key] = val;
  return ret;
}
```

Just wondering if there's a one-liner.

Comment: Do you mean: var ret={key, val};      ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, RobG! (derr ^_^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, in ES2015:

```
{
    ['foo']: 123
}
```

And there is no really simple and "fair" one in ES5.1

References:

- https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals

Answer (score 0):

It looks like is not possible in pure JavaScript. 
You need to make the object first, then use [] to set it.

However, is possible in frameworks. For instance, in ES.

[Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

[JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Comment: There will be in [*ES6*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer). ;-)