# Variable in ajax for name of variable. Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying use varible for name in data. I need to get this: $_POST['**specialName**'];

```
 sampleName = "specialName";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        sampleName: value
    },
    success: function(data) {};
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable

Comment: i havent found it. can you give me url?

Comment: Its two differend questions. My is simpler and concrete. But i have found the answer in russian comunity. Never mind. Newbee can ask quiastion like this "ajax name of variable" and becouse of you wont find the answer.