# Add an object property as object id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
$.post('page.php', {prop.name: prop.hash}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Note that, `prob` is an object and (`name`,`hash`) are properties.

The problem in `prop.cr_name`, always give me this error message:
`SyntaxError: missing : after property id`

Also I have changed the way from `prop.name` to `prop['name']` but the problem still occur.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data as query string

```
$.post('page.php', prop.name + '=' + prop.hash, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

or you need to create object in the following method , [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal) , [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

```
var data={};
data[prop.name] = prop.hash;

$.post('page.php',  data , function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

or as an array

```
$.post('page.php',  [{ name : prop.name, value : prop.hash }], function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Doc : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: It's not only related to jquery's ajax but to object declaration in general

Comment: Thank you, the first way does not work, but the second way worked fine. also thank you for reopen my question.

Answer (score 0):

create array like

```
var a=[{ name : prop.name, value : prop.hash }];
```

and pass to method like

```
$.post('page.php',a, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```