# Double "for" loop (loop in loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < settings.wrap.find('.tt_selectedRow').length; i++) {

    for (var k = 0; k < settings.columnName.length; k++) {

        var tt_obj = {
        settings.columnName[k]: 
        $(settings.wrap.find('.tt_selectedRow [data-tt_column=' + settings.columnName[k] + ']')[i]).text(), };
    }
    tt_data.push(tt_obj);
}
```

I need to do the `k` loop to obtain name of `data-tt_column` and them the `i` loop to obtain number of array preaviously created

What's wrong? when i start function = `Unexpected token .` on first `settings.columnName[k]`

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: What is `settings.wrap`?  There is not enough of your code here.

Comment: `settings.columnName[k]` is not a valid object literal, you're taking the wrong approach to fill the object (Which can easily be fixed by firstly declaring an empty object and, **then**, by filling it). Besides, what is `settings.wrap`? I would most care about that at such a point and, then, we may move on by fixing the object (check this for reference, it's quite important to actually know (almost) everything about javascript objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong field name definition. This one will be right :

```
for (var i = 0; i < settings.wrap.find('.tt_selectedRow').length; i++) {

    for (var k = 0; k < settings.columnName.length; k++) {

        var tt_obj = {};
        tt_obj[settings.columnName[k]] = $(settings.wrap.find('.tt_selectedRow [data-tt_column=' + settings.columnName[k] + ']')[i]).text();
    }
    tt_data.push(tt_obj);
}
```