# How to set variable key and value in Google Chrome local storage sync?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6

I'm using Chrome's version of localStorage ([`chrome.storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)) and I want to use a variable key and value when setting what data to store with it.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({ user: id }, callback);
```

where the user and id are dynamically generated.

This:

```
var user = "Bob";
var id = "81256309";

chrome.storage.sync.set({ user: id }, callback);
```

doesn't work because it doesn't interpret `user` and `id` as their underlying string values and, as a result, syncs to Chrome with this object: `{ user: id }`.

[I know how to do this with normal JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable) but the method in that thread won't work in this case because I don't have control over the storage.sync object of my Google account.

Comment: var obj = {}; obj[user] = id; chrome.storage.sync.set(obj,callback)

Comment: @kzahel thanks for the quick reply. How would I later retrieve that with chrome.storage.sync.get ?

Comment: @kzahel unfortunately, I don't think that your method works with multiple key value pairs because if I do  
`var obj = {}; obj[user] = id; chrome.storage.sync.set(obj,callback)` and then `var obj = {}; obj[user2] = id2; chrome.storage.sync.set(obj,callback)` the first obj gets overwritten.

Comment: @kzahel I suppose you could rename obj to obj + some randomly generated id but then there's the problem of referencing that when you want to get the data later

Comment: @kzahel creating multiple KV pairs in the same `obj` and accessing it with the `chrome.storage.sync.get` `items.obj[user]` is another possibility but that means that each get request returns all the data, which is not ideal because it would severely limit how much data you can store

Comment: Use indexeddb if you want to store tons of stuff?

Comment: @kzahel the 102,400 bytes quota for `chrome.storage.sync` is perfect for my purposes. The problem is that if I use one `obj` to store all my KV pairs I will, because it's a single item, be limited to a 8,192 bytes quota. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync

Comment: You should re-state your question because it is not clear what you are trying to do, and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Computed property names in ES6](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames), you could use

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({ [user]: id }, callback);
```