# How possible is it to have dynamic chrome.storage.sync.set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

With using the Chrome API, I am wondering how I would go about passing an array though the sync.set ability.

```
var itemname = ["itemid1", "itemid2", "itemid3"]
var itemvalue = ["itemval1", "itemval2", "itemval"]

for (i = 0; i < itemname.length; ++i)  {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ itemname[i]: itemvalue [i] });
}
```

Information would be stored within the `itemname` and `itemvalue` which would be variables for their inner value. Now I know to a certain degree that this isn't exactly how this works, and if anyone has a possible closest working solution for storing many different pieces of information using one line rather than having multiple `chrome.storage.sync.set` tags cluttering the code, that would be amazing.

Comment: Use ES6 syntax or an intermediate object: [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](//stackoverflow.com/a/2274327)

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to wrap your items into a separate object and sync it once:

```js
var itemname = ["itemid1", "itemid2", "itemid3"]
var itemvalue = ["itemval1", "itemval2", "itemval"]

var obj = {};
for (i = 0; i < itemname.length; ++i)  {
  obj[itemname[i]] = itemvalue [i]
}
storage.sync.set({ items: obj });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How does one go about to `sync.get` these saved values? `items.itemid1` Yes?

Comment: `chrome.storage.sync.get({ itemid1: true }); ` ?

Comment: For it to be stored like `chrome.storage.sync.set({ itemid1: itemid1}); ` and possibly not need two arrays, but have a single one.

Comment: And these are individual store items. Not storing one whole array together.

Comment: @UndefinedUsername yeap, you can get them using `chrome.storage.sync.get('items', function(res) { res.items.itemid1 });`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779855/how-to-set-variable-key-and-value-in-google-chrome-local-storage-sync