# Object key name with a variable

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to make an object which has one key name taken from a variable.

```
var key="KeyName"
var obj={
 key:"value"
}
```

When I want to access the "KeyName" key,I can't because I have just created a key with the name "key" not "KeyName".
I found a soution here :

[JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

```
var key="KeyName"
var obj={
[key]:"value"
}
```

But it doesn't work.
What to do?

Comment: Your last example probably doesn't work because your browser (which is what?) doesn't support it.

Comment: the feature was introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) if your system doesn't support that you cannot use this method. You can find an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this: first initialize the object and use brackets `[]` to set key value.

```
var obj = {};
var key = "KeyName";
obj[key] = "value";
```