# yui compressor giving syntax error for valid javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, yui-compressor

I am getting syntax error while compressing js file using a command line tool yuicompressor jar.

> [ERROR] 1796:28:invalid property id

I have a variable `commentGroup`. I want to push it as JSON object with the value of `commentGroup as key`. To achieve this I referred this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508490/3148590).

```
var commentGroup = 'owner';
var groupIndex= [];
groupIndex.push({[commentGroup]: 1}); // Error line 1796
```

Why is it telling invalid property id?

I am using `yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar`

I have tried above code on [JavaScript/CSS/HTML Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/)

**Output**

```
{
  "message": "Unexpected token: name (commentGroup)",
  "filename": 0,
  "line": 3,
  "col": 18,
  "pos": 66
}
```

I think YUI compressor does not understand `{[commentGroup]: 1}`

I got the solution for above problem, I need to declare temporary variable, then I put my object as a key into that variable and then pushed into the array.

```
var commentGroup = 'owner';
var aObject= {};
aObject[commentGroup]= 1;  
var groupIndex= [];
groupIndex.push(aObject);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because what you have used is ES6 syntax. And YUI Compressor is not supporting ES6 yet.There's [open ticket here](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/262).