# How to add variable as json key in javaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a json object with key value pair. I want to add a variable as key but i dont know how to add. I tried with some code but it dosen't set the variable value. How can i solve this?

```
var id='second'
var obj={'first': 123, id: 23}
console.log(obj); //{first: 123, id: 23}
```

But i want to be the result like this.

```
{first: 123, second: 23}
```

Please help me to fix this problem. Thankyou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable) and literally hundreds of others

Comment: You don't have a "JSON object". See [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Yes it is a Object Literal Notation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one. This is works.
`id='second'`
`var obj={'first': 123,[id]: 23}`

Answer (score 10):

If you have built the object already, you can add the property by

```
obj[id] = 23
```

If you have not built the object and are putting it together at that moment:

```
var obj = {
    first: 123,
    [id]: 23
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is simple:

obj[id]=123;

Comment: its chows the result like `{first: 123, id: 23, second: 123}` but i want with out ` id: 23` in a efficient way

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you trying to do. So you want to change id: 23 to second: 123? Then add delete obj["id"]; before

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
obj[id] = 23
```

It'll add a key named by the value of variable `id` and set its value to `23`.