# Create an object and give it a variable name javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say i want to create an object that is named using a variable? how would i do this? is it even possible?

```
var aName = "obusdiofu";

aName = {check: true, person: false};

console.log(obusdiofu); //gives me the newly created object?
```

Comment: It is not possible to construct variable names dynamically without using `eval()`, and you probably shouldn't do that without good reason. You *can* construct object property names dynamically.

Comment: **cough** `eval()` **cough**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly. You'd want to create an object first, then you can store things as custom properties of that object.

```
var names = {}
var aName = 'obusdiofu'
names[aName] = { check: true, person: false }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing in Javascript, however , you could do something like this :

```
var aName = "obusdiofu";

this[aName] = {check: true, person: false};

console.log(obusdiofu);

// Or if the code is outside the global scope, then
// you should access it like so :
console.log(this.obusdiofu);
```

**Note: You should be careful though when assigning the aName variable, because not all characters are accepted .**

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer first, per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!):

> ## Do not ever use `eval`!
>
> `eval()` is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run `eval()` with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension. More importantly, a third-party code can see the
>   scope in which `eval()` was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks
>   in ways to which the similar `Function` is not susceptible.

That being said, you can achieve something along those lines like this:

```js
let aName = 'obusdiofu';
eval(`var ${aName} = {check: true, person: false}`);
console.log(obusdiofu);
```

I can't see why that would ever be necessary, and due to the issues with `eval()` you would be better off doing something like one of the other posted answers.