# Javascript doesn't consider my variable a variable (array issue)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

As explained in the title I'm having a hard time trying to make a thing that seems simple work. Here's a simple example, it's easier to understand.

```js
var reccords = {
  1: {
    1: [10, 'zorro'],
    2: [25, 'ro']
  },
  2: {
    1: [20, "dim"]
  }
}

var time = 5;
reccords[3] = {
  time: [2, 'michel']
}; //time isn't considered as a variable

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = reccords[3]['time'][0];
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = reccords[3][5][0]; //does not work, how to make it work?
```

```html
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: time is not an array as you are using it

Comment: Made you a snippet. You need to fix the console errors

Comment: records is also an object of array sno? not an array of arrays

Comment: The problem is that you don't have in records[3] a property '5'.

Comment: You likely MEANT to do this: `var time = 5;
reccords[3] = {}; reccords[3][time]=[2, 'michel']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following use `[time]` to set value of `time` i.e. 5 as the property of object. With this, in case of `reccords[3]['time'][0]`, you need to use `reccords[3][time][0]` as `records[3]` does not have `time` property.

```js
var reccords = {1:{1:[10,'zorro'],2:[25,'ro']}, 2:{1:[20,"dim"]}}

var time=5;
reccords[3] = {[time]:[2, 'michel']}; //time isn't considered as a variable

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = reccords[3][time][0];
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = reccords[3][5][0];
```

```html
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great!

Comment: @ZorroLeDozo - Glad to help you :)

Comment: ES6 notation to have `{[variable]: ...`https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508530/295783

Comment: Plains JS method: `var time = 5; reccords[3] = {}; reccords[3][time]=[2, 'michel']`