# How to add dynamic key with value in existing Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects

I have an existing javascript object.

```
let existingObject = {
    1: {
        'prop1': 'prop1 value',
        'prop2': 'prop2 value'
    },
    2: {
        'prop1': 'prop1 value',
        'prop2': 'prop2 value'
    },
    3: {
        'prop1': 'prop1 value',
        'prop2': 'prop2 value'
    }
}
```

I want to add a property to that existing object. My new key value is:

```
const key = 4;
const value = {
    'prop1': 'prop1 value',
    'prop2': 'prop2 value'
}
```

After appending the key and value, my new object should be,

```
const newObject = {
    1: {
        'prop1': 'prop1 value',
        'prop2': 'prop2 value'
    },
    2: {
        'prop1': 'prop1 value',
        'prop2': 'prop2 value'
    },
    3: {
        'prop1': 'prop1 value',
        'prop2': 'prop2 value'
    },
    4: {
        'prop1': 'prop1 value',
        'prop2': 'prop2 value'
    }
}
```

Here the key is a dynamic value. Whenever I try to append this key-value, the key is becoming the variable name.

How can I solve this issue?

NB: For creating the existing object I am using lodash.

Comment: `existingObject[key] = value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object) and [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463)

Comment: If you want consecutive numeric keys, why don't you use an array?

Comment: You haven't even shown any of the code attempts here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and using [Computed Property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) (example `{[key]: value}`):

```js
let existingObject = {
    1: {'prop1': 'prop1 value', 'prop2': 'prop2 value'},
    2: {'prop1': 'prop1 value', 'prop2': 'prop2 value'},
    3: {'prop1': 'prop1 value', 'prop2': 'prop2 value'}
}

const key = 4;
const value = {'prop1': 'prop1 value', 'prop2': 'prop2 value'}

Object.assign(existingObject, {[key]: value});
console.log(existingObject);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

But, as others have commented to you, this is easy as just:

```
existingObject[key] = value;
```