# Jquery push key with child array

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, push

I have a main array

```
var mainArray = new Array();
```

I have a key(id) and sub array with key pairs "foo" and "zulu"

```
var id = 2;
var bar = 14;
var alpha = 88;
```

I want to push this into the main array structured as so

```
id => array(
     "foo" => bar,
     "zulu" => alpha
)
```

I tried this but it doesn't add the parent key, only the child array

```
mainArray.push(id = {
     "foo" : bar,
     "zulu" : alpha,
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways you can choose one up to your need

**1st Way:**  By using `var mainArray = {};` as an object and `mainArray[id]` to set a key

```js
var mainArray = {};
var id = 2;
var bar = 14;
var alpha = 88;

mainArray[id] = {
     "foo" : bar,
     "zulu" : alpha
};

console.log(mainArray);
console.log(mainArray[id]);
```

**2nd Way:** By using `.push({ [id] : {   }  })` *With `[id]` id will print as a value*

```js
var mainArray = [];
var id = 2;
var bar = 14;
var alpha = 88;

mainArray.push({
  [id] : {
     "foo_1" : bar,
     "zulu_1" : alpha
  }
});
console.log(mainArray);
console.log(mainArray[0][id]); // use 1,2 ,3.... instead of 0
```

**Ref:** [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object) And [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Comment: It's just printing id as "id" instead of value

Comment: 1st Way will print id as a value but 2nd way doesn't .. please see my last updated answer @user300979

Comment: @user300979 now both ways returned id as a value .. please check the updated answer