# nodejs use local variable into object title

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, variables

I'm wondering why my variables do not recognized into my object title?
I'm using query variable like this :

```
var query_type = req.query.type; // age (12)
var query_search = req.query.search; // name (robert)

var map = {
    query_type : query_search 
}
```

When I try to print the map, the output has something wrong.

```
console.dir(map);
{query_type : "robert"}
```

Why my query_type do not recognize in my object?
I want to print like below :

```
{"age" : "robert"}
```

Comment: It's unclear why that output was unexpected, you want `{ [query_type]: query_search }`.

Comment: or Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dynamic property name with square bracket notation:

```
var map = {
    [query_type]: query_search
};
```