# How to escape an JSON-string of an object correctly if the object content is user generated?

Tags: javascript, html, json, escaping, user-input

I want to use the var `s` for the value-field of an option-element. How to escape correctly in the sense to contain user input used for key and value?

```
var key='highway'; var value='track';
var s = JSON.stringfy({ [key]:value }, undefined,'');
s = s.replace(/'/g,'\\\'').replace(/"/g,'\\"');
var h = '<option type="text" value="' + s + '">'+key+'</option>';
// ...
document.getElementById('aSelectElement').innerHTML = h;
```

Edit: Actually I use it for an option-Element instead of an input element as mentioned first.

If I select the result in the browser, and let it me show the generated html, it shows something like:

```
<option value="{\" highway\":\"track\"}"="">highway track</option>
```

Which adds the question, why there is a whitespace in front of the highway?

Comment: The var declaration `var value:'test';` is invalid syntax. Should be `var value='test';`

Comment: The code `{ [key]:value }` should be `{ key: value }`. You can't use an array as a key in a Javascript object, nor in a JSON object. When you use a key which is not a string, Javascript silently converts it to a string.

Comment: @kaya3 Starting with ES6 this is working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable

Comment: Oh, you are right. I remember seeing that syntax before but I don't write for ES6 myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also recomment using DOM elements rather than building HTML as a string, as in the other answer. But if you really don't want to do that, you can convert any double quotes in the JSON to the HTML entity `&quot;`, so they won't terminate the `value` attribute.

```js
var key = 'first';
var value = 'test';
var s = JSON.stringify({
  [key]: value
}, undefined, '').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
var h = '<input type="text" value="' + s + '">';
document.getElementById('aDiv').innerHTML = h;
```

```html
<div id="aDiv"></div>
```

Comment: With `'&quot;'` in the replace instead of `'\\"'`, which I used first, it does work. Ty!

Comment: Naturally. HTML doesn't use backslashes for escaping.

Comment: Now that you say it, it's so obvious. :) Another question: Which editor for html, javascript and php would you suggest or are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to build HTML as a string; you can create an input element and set its value programmatically:

```
// ...
var inputElem = document.createElement('input');
inputElem.type = 'text';
inputElem.value = s;
// ..
document.getElementById('aDiv').appendChild(inputElem);
```

Note that this isn't quite equivalent because setting `innerHTML` removes all the existing content from the div, but calling `appendChild` doesn't. If you do need to replace the existing content, you can do this by [removing the existing child nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild#Simple_examples) first.

Comment: I'm not very fond of appendChild-syntax. Worst was that it triggered Firefox (I believe it was version 30-something) to let the loading animation on the top beside the http-adress run. People would have thought the program would connect to the internet, whereas it is a 100% offline application.

Comment: OK, well if you absolutely must avoid `appendChild` for some reason, you could create the input element as an HTML string with a blank value, but give it some id so you can do `document.getElementById('the_input').value = s`. The solution is still to set `.value` programmatically.

Comment: Another question: Which editor for html, javascript and php would you suggest or are you using?