# How to variable value assigned in object key?

Tags: javascript

I tried to sample code for variable value assign in n object key using typescript. but it's not working can anyone give suggestion on value assign an object key.

**Example Code**

```
const data = "hai";
const objec = {
    data:{"dddd":"dfdfdf"}
}
console.log(objec)
```

**I need Output like this**

```
{hai:{dddd:"dfdfdf"}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]`

```js
const data = "hai";
const objec = {
    [data]:{"dddd":"dfdfdf"}
}
console.log(objec)
```