# assigment to json object field from string array doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, variable-assignment

I'm trying to create a json object and push it to an array.I want to assign json object's field from an string array.When i write manually (for example  `{exampleField:"exampleValue"}`) is working for me but when I try assign exampleField from an string array it says `Unexpected token,expected ","` . I think I'm missing very simple thing but i couldnt figure out.

The codes are below

```js
export function excelNull(userReq) {
  var i = 0
  var f = 0
  let values = []
  let headers = Object.keys(userReq[0])
  console.log(headers)
  for (f = 0; f < headers.length; f++) {
    for (i = 0; i < userReq.length; i++) {
      if (isNullOrUndefined(userReq[i][headers[f]])) {
        values.push({
          headers[f]: userReq[i]["__rowNum__"] + 1 + ". satırda " + headers[f] + " boş olamaz"
        })
      }
    }
  }
  return values
}
```

when i write something different instead of headers[f] it is working. But i wanna dynamic assign from an string array.

So I can get an json object array like `[{field1:"val1"},{field2:"val2"}....]`

I hope I am clear with my explanation.

Comment: you want: `values.push({[headers[f]]: ... })`  mind the extra `[]`  (duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Comment: what values `headers[f]:` have?

Comment: @Yoshi thank you so much.This is exactly what i want

Comment: @StepUp string values, headers[f] is a string array