# JSON Object key value pair function

Tags: javascript, json, object

Why i am unable to pass "abc" to someKey

```
function convertToKeyValuePair(someKey,someValue){

    var map = {someKey : someValue};
    return JSON.stringify(map);
}
print(convertToKeyValuePair("abc","xyz"));
```

O/P = `{"someKey":"sdfdf"}`

Expected O/P = `{"abc":"xyz"}`

Comment: You want dynamic keys, e.g. `var map = {[someKey]: someVaue};`

Comment: I believe that output is O/P = `{"someKey":"xyz"}`. If so just use computed property values  -  `var map = {[someKey]: someValue};`

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable

Answer (score 0):

As you’re passing key dynamically so you’ve to use bracket around it like:
`{ [someKey]: someValue }`

Answer (score 0):

You want dynamic keys.

```js
let key = 'yo';
let obj = {key: 0}; // creates {"key": 0}
let objDynamic = {[key]: 0}; // creates {"yo": 0};

console.log(obj);
console.log(objDynamic);
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by the comment of @junvar, passing keys to objects without quotes is syntactic sugar and both of the following examples will give the same result:

```
{ "someVar": someValue }
{ someVar: someValue }
```

To use the value of a variable as a key you have to use square brackets as in:

```
{ [someVar]: someValue }
```