# MongoDB & Unable to set value depending on variable name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object

Coming across something i thought would have worked, but does not.

I have the following function that takes an input and needs to update one value in the mongodb.

```
const updateSkillXP = (data) =>{
    //data = { username:username, sk:sk, xp:100 }

    const collection = db.collection('player');
    let q = {username:data.username}

    //craft a key depending on what skill code comes through.
    let s = "skills."+data.sk;
    u = {$set: {s : data.xp}}

    return collection.updateOne(q,u,(err,res) =>{
        if(err) console.log(err);
    })
}
```

The MongoDB document looks as follows

```
player = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    username:"foo",
    skills : { //I need one of the following to update.
        atk:0,
        str:0,
        def:0,
        hp:0
    }
}
```

When I executed the above, it added 'S' Property, but i was expecting to change the value of say 'atk' to what ever xp came through?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
[JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

```
const updateSkillXP = (data) =>{
    //data = { username:username, sk:sk, xp:100 }

    const collection = db.collection('player');
    let q = {username:data.username}
    let s = "skills."+data.sk;
    let obj = {};
    obj[s] = data.xp;
    u = {$set: obj}

    return collection.updateOne(q,u,(err,res) =>{
        if(err) console.log(err);
    })
}
```