# Replace a number/string with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am sending data to firebase with the following piece of code which is working:

```
var mac = "10:10:10:10";
var ref = rootRef.child('user/' + 'nicolas');

if(pass == "4920" ){
 ref.update({
   1: mac
 });
}
```

What I need to do is replace the '1' with a variable, since I need to change the value dinamically. I tried the following:

```
var mac = "10:10:10:10";
var ref = rootRef.child('user/' + 'nicolas');
var index = 1;

if(pass == "4920" ){
 ref.update({
   index: mac
 });
}
```

But the result is that the mac address is stored inside "index" directory, and no the directory called "1". Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal) Also see [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable) and [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the variable name within brackets and it will parse as the actual variable

```
if(pass == "4920" ){
      ref.update({
      [index]: mac
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Realtime Database doesn't really have "directories".  It has nested nodes.  If you want to continue nesting more nodes under `ref`, you can just keep adding them on with calls to child().

```
var ref = rootRef.child('user/' + 'nicolas');
var indexRef = ref.child('1');
indexRef.update(mac);
```

If you want to pass an object with a key that has a value of a varible, you can use JavaScript syntax for that (which has nothing to do with Firebase):

```
ref.update({
   [index]: mac
});
```