# How to dynamically assign the name of a key in an object?

Tags: javascript

```
const key = 'name'
const tempObj = {key: 'shiyuq'}
console.log(tempObj)
// {key: 'shiyuq'}
// but I want a object like this  {name: 'shiyuq'}
```

Finally I find a new way to modify object's key value,code follows like this:

```
const tempObj = {[key]: 'shiyuq'}
console.log(tempObj)
```

I want to know why this can work and what does **[ ]** mean in this situation? thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Computed property names**

Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression in brackets `[]`, that will be computed and used as the property name. This is reminiscent of the bracket notation of the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) syntax, which you may have used to read and set properties already.

Now you can use a similar syntax in object literals, too:

```js
// Computed property names (ES2015)
let i = 0
let a = {
  ['foo' + ++i]: i,
  ['foo' + ++i]: i,
  ['foo' + ++i]: i
}

console.log(a.foo1) // 1
console.log(a.foo2) // 2
console.log(a.foo3) // 3

let param = 'size'
let config = {
  [param]: 12,
  ['mobile' + param.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + param.slice(1)]: 4
}

console.log(config) // {size: 12, mobileSize: 4}
```

---

Copy&Paste from -> [Object initializer - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Answer (score 0):

Great. Hope you're clear with the use of **[ ]** notation. But to work in a real-time scenario, Where we get a **large set of data** in a **dynamic** format of objects not a single key at a time.

I have created a **code-snippet** that basically extends your answer in a more **advanced** manner with **sets of objects** data in place.

**Example**:-

**Step-1**: Let's create a key's object i.e, **keysObj**

**Step-2**: Let's create a temp object i.e, **tempObj**

**Step-3**: Finally create the variable function i.e, **mainObj**

```js
const keysObj = {key1: "firstName", key2: "lastName"}; 

const tempObj = {key1: "Naheed", key2: "Shareef"};

const mainObj = Object.keys(tempObj).reduce((obj,k) => Object.assign(obj, { [keysObj[k]]: tempObj[k]  }),{});

console.log(mainObj);
```

**URL:** https://es6console.com/kc652vic/