# Conditional position left/right in React style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to place properly property right/left into react's component style object?

```
const [pos, setPos] = useState(null);
useEffect(()=>{
  if(someCondition){setPos('left')}
  else{setPos('right')}
})
return (
  <div style={{`${pos}:0`}} />
)
```

My solution above does not work. I receive string and in style i need object prop. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STOP ! `useEffect` is in an infinite loop**

Each time you `setPos(...)` , the component re-renders and calls `useEffect()` again . You want to avoid that, hence you will have to pass in a secondary argument of `[]`, to make it behave like `componentDidMount` which basically stop the `useEffect` effect from firing more than once. Coz now it depends on no elements i.e `[]`

```
const [pos, setPos] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=>{
  if(someCondition){setPos('left')}
  else{setPos('right')}
}, []);

return (
  <div style={{ [pos] : 0 }} />
)
```

The infinite loop of changing `pos` was stopping your component from rendering properly.

Link : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

(See the note at the end of the page)

> Note
>
> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values
> from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over
> time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will
> reference stale values from previous renders. Learn more about how to
> deal with functions and what to do when the array changes too often.
>
> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.
>
> If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect
> will always have their initial values. While passing [] as the second
> argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and
> componentWillUnmount mental model, there are usually better solutions
> to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React
> defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing
> extra work is less of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Code below should solve your problem. More info about how the variable's value can be used as object's key can be found on this StackOverflow [link /question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable).

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(someCondition){setPos('left')}
  else{setPos('right')}
})
return (
  <div style={{ [pos]: 0}} />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `style={{ [pos]: 0 }}`.
Also don't forget to add position: 'absolute' so

```
style = {{[pos]:0, position: 'absolute }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(someCondition){setPos('left')}
  else{setPos('right')}
})
return (
  <div style={{ [pos]: 0}} />
)
```

you can also pass position in style for better styling, like `<div style={{ [pos]: 0, position: 'absolute`}} />`

As per my view, don't use `useEffect()` on every change. [The infinite loop of changing `pos` maybe affact your component from rendering properly]. just go through the doc once to have a clear and better understanding of react hooks. [ref this link](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-component-lifecycle-methods-with-react-hooks-efcd04987805)