# Can we use concatenated values and variables for Object Keys?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object

```
let x = { "propName": "response" }
```

Is there a way we can change the key name for the object. I would like to pass an index for the propName like

```
{ "prop1Name": "response" }
```

Is there a way to do this, I know I cant do it like this but, I tried it with

```js
var obj = { "prop"+i+"Name": "response" };
console.log(obj);
```

But, it failed ofcourse.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new ES6/Babel syntax of `{[keyfromvariable]:"value"}`, so, in your case...

```js
var i = "1";
var obj = { ["prop"+i+"Name"]: "response" };
console.log(obj);
```

If you don't have ES6/Babel as an option, you can define the object first and then use `[]`...

```js
    var i = "1";
    var obj = {};
    obj ["prop"+i+"Name"] = "response" ;
    console.log(obj);
```