# Chrome Extension - Chrome.storage - Why does chrome.storage.sync.get returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage, google-chrome-app

For some reason my getStorageKeyValue method returns undefined instead of the value previously set.
I am beating my head over this for approximately 3 days now. The google searches didn't solve my problem and I beg you please help! How to fix this?

This is my current JavaScript code:

```
// Sets a key and stores its value into the storage
function setStorageKey(key, value){
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ key: value });
}

// Gets a key value from the storage
function getStorageKeyValue(key){
    chrome.storage.sync.get([key], function(result) {
        return result.key;
    });
}

// Set a new key inside the storage
let value = 10;
setStorageKey("K1", value);

// Get the value of the key passed in parameter from the storage
let receivedValue = getStorageKeyValue("K1");

alert("Set value: "+value+" --- Received value: "+receivedValue);
// Results in: Set value: 10 --- Received Value: undefined
```

**Solution Found:**

```
// Sets a key and stores its value into the storage
function setStorageKey(key, value){
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ [key]: value });
}

// Gets a key value from the storage
function getStorageKeyValue(key, onGetStorageKeyValue){
    chrome.storage.sync.get([key], function(result) {
       onGetStorageKeyValue(result[key]);
    });
}

// Running our code to see the result:
// 1) Set value & Save it to storage
let value = 10;
setStorageKey("K1", value);

//) 2) Get saved value from storage and display a warning message with the value
getStorageKeyValue("K1", function(key) {
  alert("Set value: "+value+" --- Received value: "+ key);
});
// Results in: Set value: 10 --- Received Value: 10
```

Many thanks for your responses and help.
I hope that this question will be useful for other developers.

**Special thanks to:**
johannchopin and Andreas. Their responses helped me to solve my issue.

Comment: get set methods are async so you can get and set values from callbacks but not as methods return value. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: @wOxxOm The dupe targets won't fix the problem completely. `.set({ key: value })` stores the value as `"key"` and not as what ever is stored in the parameter `key` -> [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Comment: Ah, I forgot to link that one. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.storage.sync.get` is an asynchronous method, that's why you need to give a callback to it when it has done getting the storage. So you can't adopt a procedural code structure for that. A solution would be to use a callback structure:

```js
function setStorageKey(key, value){
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ key: value });
}

function getStorageKeyValue(key, onGetStorageKeyValue){
    chrome.storage.sync.get([key], function(result) {
       onGetStorageKeyValue(result.key);
    });
}

let value = 10;
setStorageKey("K1", value);

getStorageKeyValue("K1", function(key) {
  alert("Set value: "+value+" --- Received value: "+ key);
});
```

Comment: I tried to use your code but unfortunately it leads to the same result ( "Received value: undefined"

Comment: @Corey See my comment on your question and the third dupe target

Comment: johannchopin and @Andreas I would like to say a big thank-you! You really helped me to solve my issue!