# Assigning a key value pair to an empty object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

I'm wondering why I'm not able to assign a key / value pair to a given object in JavaScript using some forms of syntax versus others.

```
function updateObjectWithKeyAndValue(object, key, value) {
  var newPair = {};

  // Why does the syntax below need to be used to create the key / value pair?
  
  newPair[key] = value;

  // Why do "newPair.key = value;" or "newPair = { key: value }" not work?

  var newObject = Object.assign({}, object, newPair);
  return newObject;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: With both methods you are creating another property with literally the name "key".

Comment: `object[key] = value`

Comment: Also note that you can simply do `object[key] = value;` instead.

Comment: Duplicate: [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Comment: `newPair = { [key]: value };` would work, if you want to go nuts.

Comment: `object.key` is equivalent to `object["key"]`

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

I understand now that `newObject.key` sets the key name to `key` while `newObject[key]` allows for the `key` parameter to be passed properly.

I also understand that `object[key] = value;` will achieve the same end result, but I'm trying to preserve the original object and instead return a clone with the new data.