# push to array as variable, not string

Tags: javascript

i am trying to do the following:

```
var cars = [];
var newCar = "toyota";
cars.push({
newCar: {
year: 2000,
}
})
```

it saves newCar as "newCar", not as "toyota".
How can I do it?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+object+key+from+variable) of [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11508463/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a dynamic property key.

```
var cars = [];
var newCar = "toyota";
cars.push({
 [newCar]: {
 year: 2000,
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use computed property name

```js
var cars = [];
var newCar = "toyota";
cars.push({
[newCar]: {
year: 2000,
}
})

console.log(cars)
```