# MongoDB addToSet by condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm working with MongoDB and I wanted to add something to a set, depending on some conditions.

So, say if someone did `x` then it would add to a set called `y`, but if someone did `y` it would add to a set called `x`.

My first thought was the ternary operator, and I used the following code:

```js
let toAdd = x ? 'y' : 'x'
// Jump cut to $addToSet
$addToSet: {
 toAdd: 'thing'
}
```

However, this doesn't actually add anything to the database.
How could I specify a certain set using a variable?

Comment: Doesn't it add _anything_? I think it adds _something_ (provided that the rest of the query/configuration is fine)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Nope. Nothing. Checked the database, no new data was added.

Comment: are you sure any document was matched to update? What does the update result say how many documents where affected?

Comment: @Thilo I'm 100% Positive I'm using an actual document, when I use a regular set, EX
`'x'` it updates and everything.

Comment: What language is this? Did you mean to make the field name a variable? Then you may have to use something like `$addToSet[toAdd] = 'thing'`.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/11508463/14955

Comment: Oh yeah, It is javascript. I'll try that out.