# creating an object inside a for loop using the iterator

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this function:

```
//prices is an array of numbers

function mapPrices(prices) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    newArray.push({ i: prices[i] });
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

If I run mapPrices([1,2,3,4]), I expect to get:

```
[{0: 1}, {1: 2}, {2: 3}, {3: 4}]
```

instead, I am getting:

```
[{"i": 1}, {"i": 2}, {"i": 3}, {"i": 4}]
```

Why?

How can I get what I want?

Comment: This is how objects work: `{ i: 'foo' }` is syntactic sugar for a key named `"i"`. You probably want `{ [i]: 'foo' }`.

Answer (score 3):

```js
newArray.push({ i: prices[i] });
```

Here `i` is read as the key, so it's used as string.

Since you want the `value of i`, you'll need to use `[]` brackets to let JS know it's a variable:

```js
newArray.push({ [i]: prices[i] });
```

```js
function mapPrices(prices) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    newArray.push({ [i]: prices[i] });
  }
  return newArray;
}

const res = mapPrices([1,2,3,4]);
console.log(res);
```

More info, also about the history with ES6; please take a look at

- [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)