# How can I add a dynamic Id to array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

suggest i have this object of nested array

```
let order={
a:1
b:2
service:[
1:{a:1,b:3},
2:{a:3,b:4}
]
}
```

so i want to insert object to service array with new dynamic id
i tried that

````
let serviceOrder={a:5,b:6}
let id=uuid4(); //example 4
let newSer={...order.service,id:serviceOrder}
```
````

but i get this

```
service:[
1:{a:1,b:3},
2:{a:3,b:4},
id:{a:5,b:6}
]
```

whereas i want to get this

```
service:[
1:{a:1,b:3},
2:{a:3,b:4},
3:{a:5,b:6}
]
```

so how i can  do this
thank in advance to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Comment: To dynamically insert a value key, enclose the variable that is to be the key of the specific value in square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
let id=uuid4(); //example 4
let newSer={...order.service,[id]:serviceOrder}
```

when you want to add dynamic key to object you can use `[ ]` and you can place your variable inside `[ ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this.

```
let newSer = {}
newSer[id] = serviceOrder
```