# Use variable as map key in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, javascript-objects

How to use a variable such as users UID as the key to a map in Firestore.

I would imagine its the same principal as out of Firestore

```
const userID = "gfsueudiyeueuuuke7ue"

setDoc(docRef, {
    userID : {
        age: 11,
        name: "test"
        ... 
    }
})
```

Ive tried (userID): ...
as well as `${userID}`:

any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by putting brackets [] around [userID], alos using updateDoc as to not overwrite the document.

```
const userID = "gfsueudiyeueuuuke7ue"

updateDoc(docRef, {
    [userID] : {
        age: 11,
        name: "test"
        ... 
    }
})
```