# Create a styling rule for clsx for React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, tailwind-css, clsx

Having this clsx method which works fine:

```
const getLinkClasses = (disabled: boolean) => {
  return clsx('flex whitespace-nowrap', {
    'text-gray-500': !disabled,
    'text-gray-300 cursor-not-allowed': disabled
  });
};
```

There are two other optional variables, one for disabled and one for !disabled that are strings and can add new rules to the above method. Let's call them `disabledValue` and  `notDisabledValue`.

For example,

```
const disabledValue = 'bg-red-100'; 
const notDisabledValue = 'bg-green-100';
```

In order to add those variables, I've made the following changes:

```
export interface MyProps {
  disabledValue?: string;
  notDisabledValue?: string;
}

const getLinkClasses = (disabled: boolean, style: MyProps) => {
  const notDis = `text-gray-500 ${style.notDisabledValue ?? ''}`;
  const dis = `text-gray-300 cursor-not-allowed ${style.disabledValue ?? ''}`;

  return clsx('flex whitespace-nowrap', {
    notDis: !disabled,
    dis: disabled
  });
};
```

The problem is that those two variables, `notDis` and `dis` aren't read:

> 'notDis' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
>
> 'notDis' is assigned a value but never
> used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want to use "computed property names".

Something like this in ES6+:

```
const getLinkClasses = (disabled: boolean, style: MyProps) => {
  const notDis = `text-gray-500 ${style.notDisabledValue ?? ''}`;
  const dis = `text-gray-300 cursor-not-allowed ${style.disabledValue ?? ''}`;

  return clsx('flex whitespace-nowrap', {
    [notDis]: !disabled,
    [dis]: disabled
  });
};
```

See: [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)