# Transform complex object into key value

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "slug": "bitcoin",
    "rank": 1,
    "is_active": 1,
    "first_historical_data": "2013-04-28T18:47:21.000Z",
    "last_historical_data": "2022-02-18T11:39:00.000Z",
    "platform": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Litecoin",
    "symbol": "LTC",
    "slug": "litecoin",
    "rank": 20,
    "is_active": 1,
    "first_historical_data": "2013-04-28T18:47:22.000Z",
    "last_historical_data": "2022-02-18T11:39:00.000Z",
    "platform": null
  }
]
```

And I want to transform the array to this

```
{
  "BTC": "Bitcoin",
  "LTC": "Litecoin",
}
```

Is there a better way than this?

```
const result = {}
arr.reduce((accum, val) => {
  Object.assign(result, { [val.symbol]: val.name });
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want an array of single (random) property objects? That's unusual. Of course you might have a perfectly valid use case.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Why did you ask https://stackoverflow.com/q/71173289/218196 then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is

```
Object.fromEntries(arr.map(({symbol, name}) => [symbol, name]))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: Since this doesn't answer your question anymore, you can delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries()` an each object which will return them as an array of arrays -- each sub-array will be a key/value pair (`[key, value]`) then use `Object.assign()` to create a new object (`{[key]: value}`) to return. Then flatten it so they are all in one array.

```js
const arr=[{id:1,name:"Bitcoin",symbol:"BTC",slug:"bitcoin",rank:1,is_active:1,first_historical_data:"2013-04-28T18:47:21.000Z",last_historical_data:"2022-02-18T11:39:00.000Z",platform:null},{id:2,name:"Litecoin",symbol:"LTC",slug:"litecoin",rank:20,is_active:1,first_historical_data:"2013-04-28T18:47:22.000Z",last_historical_data:"2022-02-18T11:39:00.000Z",platform:null}];

const conv = array => {
 let objects = array.map(obj => Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => Object.assign({}, {[key]: val})));
 return objects.flat();
};

console.log(conv(arr));
```

Comment: And if I want ```{
  "BTC": "Bitcoin",
  "LTC": "Litecoin",
}``` ?

Comment: That's whole different animal, are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. Sorry

Comment: @Rodrigo: dbuchet has a solution in their delete answer: `Object.fromEntries(arr.map(({symbol, name}) => [symbol, name]))`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "slug": "bitcoin",
    "rank": 1,
    "is_active": 1,
    "first_historical_data": "2013-04-28T18:47:21.000Z",
    "last_historical_data": "2022-02-18T11:39:00.000Z",
    "platform": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Litecoin",
    "symbol": "LTC",
    "slug": "litecoin",
    "rank": 20,
    "is_active": 1,
    "first_historical_data": "2013-04-28T18:47:22.000Z",
    "last_historical_data": "2022-02-18T11:39:00.000Z",
    "platform": null
  }
]

// As suggested, here it is without having to create an initial array

let alternativeArray = arr.map((val) => {
  return {[val.symbol]: val.slug}
})

console.log(alternativeArray)
```

Here is the answer to why the object key is being set in that format:
[Javascript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Comment: Why would you push an object into a different array if ```map``` already returns a new array?

Comment: Because we are creating an object inside of the map function, and that object is what is pushed into the array. I would like to see your version without an initially created array, and push the objects into it

Comment: My comment was related to your unedited answer, now everything makes sense.