# How to create object fields dynamically based on values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object array like this:

```
const values = [{name: 'name1', index: 1}, {name: 'name2', index: 2}, {name: 'name3', index: 3}]
```

Is it possible to create such an object dynamically?

```
const result = {
  name1: 1,
  name2: 2,
  name3: 3
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What part are you specifically struggling with?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable/11508530#11508530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is the following!

```js
const values = [{name: 'name1', index: 1}, {name: 'name2', index: 2}, {name: 'name3', index: 3}];
const result = {};
values.forEach(value => result[value.name] = value.index);

console.log(result); // {name1: 1, name2: 2, name3: 3}
```