# how to initialize a typescript interface with a variable key

Tags: typescript

See the following code:

```
function createObj(key: string, value:unknown) {
  const obj = {};
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}
```

gives error:

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

I know I could write it as

```
  const obj = {} as Record<string, unknown>;
```

but I wonder if I could initialize the object in one statement, like

```
  const obj = {
    key: value
  };
```

which does not work because key is a string literal here and not the value of variable key.

Comment: const obj: Record<string, unknown> = { [key]: value }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) (referenced by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508490/2703418)) as follows:

```
function createObj(key: string, value: unknown) {
  return {
    [key]: value,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WHen you create literal empty object on the fly, TS forbids you to add any properties to it, because according to inference, it should be empty. I am talking about this line:

```js
  const obj = {};
```

Hence, in order to make it in TS way, you need to infer provided arguments:

```js
function createObj<Key extends PropertyKey, Value>(key: Key, value: Value): Record<Key, Value>
function createObj<Key extends PropertyKey, Value>(key: Key, value: Value) {
  const obj: Partial<Record<Key, Value>> = {};
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}

const result = createObj('a', 1)
result.a // number
```

`Key` - represents infered type of `key` argument

`Value` - represents infered type of `value` argument

I used `Partial<Record<Key, Value>>` type for `obj`. For `Partial` and `Record` see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

`Partial` - all values are optional

`Record` - represents a hash map data structure (regular object in javascript)

As you might have noticed, `result.a` infered as a number.

We can do better. Just add type `Json`:

```js
type Json =
  | null
  | undefined
  | string
  | number
  | Array<Json>
  | { [prop: string]: Json }

function createObj<Key extends PropertyKey, Value>(key: Key, value: Value): Record<Key, Value>
function createObj<Key extends PropertyKey, Value>(key: Key, value: Value) {
  const obj: Partial<Record<Key, Value>> = {};
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}

const result = createObj('a', 1)
result.a // 1
```

Now, `result.a` is `1`