# Use TypeScript enum instead of union for object keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, enums, union-types

I have this mapping in my React typescript project:

```
const templates = {
    TypeOne: {
      expanded: (typeOne: ItemOneType) => <ItemOne key={typeOne.id} {...typeOne} />,
    },
    TypeTwo: {
      expanded: (typeTwo: ItemTwoType) => <ItemTwo key={typeTwo.uuid} {...typeTwo} />,
    },
  };
```

Then I map the array like:

```
  <ul>
    {items.map((item) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      return templates[item.type][listType](item as any);
    })}
  </ul>
```

I also have an `enum`:

```
export enum TeaserTypeName {
  TypeOne = 'TypeOne',
  TypeTwo = 'TypeTwo',
}
```

Is there a way to use above `enum` values for the keys inside 'templates' object instead of the union `type: 'TypeOne' | 'TypeTwo';`?

Comment: Is [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwCrAIYGdhQYCeYwActqsHAN4CwAUHJicAPKLUC8cARMaQ7BeAGkbMBwDAHcIcHv1YyIvRgF9GjAMYREueDGCowAG2yHc82uLgBtLHgKSKVAHSShAXQBc1pswRwbEQAE2AQ3wAKGFYhXwBJQ1QhSQBKeQA+OEibALgAHkSjIVy8uABrYCIuGhjBTlcASxCNfzLaV0669k5W9oB6DNLUmzUxf3scfEJWF2B3JVkfPzzQMGCwiOzu5QSk5TTM7NLmQv3ZE4DK6trFiFdkZGa+9o6uu5e8weHR9QBuRhAA) what your looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the enum values for the keys inside the templates object instead of the union type 'TypeOne' | 'TypeTwo'. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
const templates = {
  [TeaserTypeName.TypeOne]: {
    expanded: (typeOne: ItemOneType) => <ItemOne key={typeOne.id} {...typeOne} />,
  },
  [TeaserTypeName.TypeTwo]: {
    expanded: (typeTwo: ItemTwoType) => <ItemTwo key={typeTwo.uuid} {...typeTwo} />,
  },
};
```