# Google Cloud Function trigger increment to event.params

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get a google cloud function to fire everytime a document is created in a subcollection, with this I want it to increment a field in the parent collection of (people). People has a map called counts, I'd like it so that each subcollection has a running total of documents for quick reference. I can do it if I hard code the line `personRef.update({counts.${collectionRef}: FieldValue.increment(1)});` in and not use ${collectionRef} but can't figure out how to do it based on a param.

```
exports.incrementPersonCount = functions.firestore
    .document("people/{personId}/{collection}/{docId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
      // Get the personId from the workout document
      const personId = context.params.personId;
      const collectionRef = context.params.collection;

      // Reference to the person document
      const personRef = admin.firestore().collection("people").doc(personId);

      // Use a transaction to make sure the update is atomic
      return admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
        const personDoc = await transaction.get(personRef);

        if (!personDoc.exists) {
          console.error(`Person with ID ${personId} not found.`);
          return;
        }

        // Update the person document with the new workoutCount value
        personRef.update({`counts.`${collectionRef}: FieldValue.increment(1)});
      });
    });
```

this gets an error and doesn't pass lint.

Comment: Build the string using Javascript string interpolation (template literal) in backticks: `\`counts.${collectionRef}\`` Or just do string math: `"counts." + collectionRef`. You might also want to read the JavaScript reference on [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and the entire [String object reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Comment: I tried both those options but still couldn't get it to work, I get the following error:
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token `

Comment: Then you also need to read this to [learn how to use a variable or computed string as an object key using square braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable). `var stringkey = ...; var obj = { [stringKey]: value }`

Comment: Since you are trying to use a string to be the key of an object, it should be: `personRef.update({[\`counts.${collectionRef}\`]: FieldValue.increment(1)});`.  That is, you need to surround the key value in `[ ]` to indicate that this is a dynamic value rather than a symbol.

Comment: Aside from the notes here on how to fix your statement, you can remove the transaction related code as well because it is not needed. The ``personRef.update({[`counts.${collectionRef}`]: FieldValue.increment(1)});`` line will throw an error when the document does not exist (`error.code === 'not-found'`) which you can use to log your error message. If the error code does not match, either rethrow the caught error or handle it another way.